# List Files from storage in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to get list of files in a directory as following.

```
    private static FileInfo[] enumerateFiles(String fullPath) {
    FileInfo[] files = null;
    File file = new File(fullPath);
    if (file.exists() && file.isDirectory()) {
        File[] fileList = file.listFiles();

        if (fileList != null) {
            ArrayList<FileInfo> fileInfos = new ArrayList<FileInfo>();
            for (File f : fileList) {
                FileInfo info = createFileInfoFromFile(f);
                if (info != null) {
                    fileInfos.add(info);
                }
            }
            files = fileInfos.toArray(new FileInfo[fileInfos.size()]);
        }
    }
    return files;
```

But **fileList** is always null.

I have defined following permissions in manifest.

```
<manifest
package="com.my.app"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".fileexplorer.activities.ExplorerActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I am not able to figure out the issue. I am building in Android studio using API 22.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android is case-sensitive. Please replace:

```
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

with:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

(if you hold `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, you do not need `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`)

If that does not address your problem, please post your code where you are calling `enumerateFiles()`, and make sure that whatever you are passing into `enumerateFiles()` points to a directory that has contents (files or subdirectories).

Comment: Just to add so it helps others. I added permissions from Android Studio by using auto complete. It added permissions in CAPS, hence causing the issue.